# Интерпретация перемененных строк scss в @media

Tags: html, css, sass, less, scss

В Less это делается так

```
@SizeSM: ~"(min-width: 768px)"
@media @SizeSM {}
```

Как такое же сделать в Scss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось как-то так.

```
$SizeSM: "(min-width: 768px)";
@media #{$SizeSM} {}
```